# Understanding TM Simulator

Tags: c++, templates, computer-science, turing-machines, computation-theory

I was just looking at the [turing machine simulator code](http://en.literateprograms.org/Turing_machine_simulator_%28C_Plus_Plus,_Template_metaprogramming%29) and came across the following statements

"The tape maps time and position to symbols. To calculate the symbol, we have to look at the machine one step earlier. *If at that time, the head was at the **requested position**, the symbol has changed according to the table depending on the previous symbol at the same position and the state the machine was in. Otherwise, the symbol didn't change.*"

What does the part in italics mean? What does ***requested position*** mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

By "requested position" he means the position that you're trying to read, i.e. the value of the template argument `pos` given to `tape`.